# Can't save captured image in folder using custom camera in android

Tags: java, android, image, android-camera

I have simple app with **custom camera** but when i take picture i can't save the **captured image** inside **Downloads** folder in emulator,instead blank folder created i don't know why and where is the mistake in my code. I searched for answers but i didn't find helpful one.

can you help please?

> Image Reader

```
final ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
            List<Surface> outputSurface = new ArrayList<>();
            outputSurface.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurface.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
            final CaptureRequest.Builder builder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            builder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
            int rotation = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
                    Image mCapturedImage;
                    mCapturedImage = imageReader.acquireLatestImage();
                    mFile = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null);
                    ImageSaver saver = new ImageSaver(mCapturedImage,getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null));
                    mBackgroundHandler.post(saver);
                }

            };
            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    showSnackBar("Image saved", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    createCameraPreview();
                }
            };
```

> ImageSaver class

```
 private static class ImageSaver implements Runnable {

        private final File mFile;
        private Image mImage;

        ImageSaver(Image image, File file) {
            mImage = image;
            mFile = file;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (mImage != null) {
                ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                buffer.get(bytes);
                FileOutputStream output = null;
                try {
                    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
                    String format = s.format(new Date());
                    String fileName = format+".jpg";
                    File file = new File(mFile, "image_" + fileName);
                    output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    output.write(bytes);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (null != output) {
                        try {
                            output.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well... you do not have any code related to a `Downloads` folder, at least in this question. If you search this page, the only place in your question where "download" appears is in your opening paragraph, not the code. Your code is set up to write the image to a file in `getExternalFilesDir(null)`, which is a reasonable choice. Otherwise, on Android 9 and older, you would need to use `Environment.getExteranlStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` instead. On Android 10+, you would need to switch to using `MediaStore` as a `ContentProvider`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is doing the correct thing, so save the image file to the device, but it is saving it to the result of the path returned here:

```
mFile = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null);
```

The external file dir is probably pointing to myapp/data/data which is the 'sandbox' data area reserved for files that your app writes to external storage.  This is not the same as the Downloads folder, which is saving files down to the shared (re: outside of sandbox) data area on the phone.

If you wanted to save to Downloads, you would probably have to write your images to an external website, then pass the https:// path to a ViewIntent which would display your image in a browser session, and give you the option to download the image from there.

In your code, you have:

```
mFile = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null);
```

But I don't see where mFile is declared in Image Reader.  In your other class, you define it as a File.  if mFile is a File, then you should probably be doing something like:

```
String mPath = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null);
File mFile = new File(mPath + "/temp.jpg");

// but I don't think you need to create a file, just use the path
ImageSaver saver = new ImageSaver(mCapturedImage,mPath);
```

Comment: so if i try it on real device where i should find it in which folder?

Comment: String spath = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(); should tell you the exact path to the directory either on a physical device or on the emulator.  In pre version 8, it was under myapp/data/data.  Now, it looks like they are storing it under device/data/data/com.myco.myapp/files.  Your best bet is to read the path returned from getExternalFilesDir().  You can look at the files by going to View/ToolWindows/DeviceFileExplorer if you are using Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks for help but i want to save the image to gallery so what i should write in the path?

Comment: If you write an image file to your Files folder, then, Android searches all app file folders to populate the Gallery.  That's probably what you want to do.  It won't appear under downloads, but it should show up under Files, and in the Gallery if it is an image file.

Comment: so should i keep it like this: `String spath = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null);`?